# Can't get data from Json array via an ajax get request

Tags: json, ajax, django

I am having a hard time getting the correct field out of an object from an ajax get request. The ajax request is in a Django app and corresponds with the view. The line:

```
console.log(data);
```

displays all the data in the object. I am trying to output the username in `console.log()` but I am not able to get it done.

I tried many variations i.e. I used filter instead of get in the Django view section. I tried to for loop over the data and use [i] but so far nothing worked.

Hopefully someone has an idea on how to solve this issue. I attached the django view, the template view and the chrome dev tools console output.

The django section view:

```
def Data(request, user_id):
    if request.is_ajax():
        sidebar_data = serializers.serialize("json",    
        [User.objects.get(id=user_id)])
        return HttpResponse(
            JsonResponse({'sidebar_data': sidebar_data}),
            content_type="application/json"
        )
    return HttpResponse("not a ajax request")
```

The template view:

```
$( ".test{{ user.user.id }}" ).click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url : ‘xxx/‘,
                dataType : 'json',
                method : 'GET',
                success: function(data)
                {   
                    // this works - outputs all data
                    console.log(data);
                    // this does not work
                    console.log(data.sidebar_data.fields[1].username);
                },
                failure: function(){  
                }
            });
        });
```

The output for the browser in chrome console:

```
Object {
sidebar_data: "[{"fields": {"username": “xxx”, "first_name": “xxx”}, "model": "auth.user", "pk": 989}]”}
```

If i use console.log(data.sidebar_data); i get the following output which is a step closer. But as soon as i try any combination with fields or username i get the undefined error.

```
[{"fields": {"username": “xx”, "first_name": “xxx”}, "model": "auth.user", "pk": 989}]
```

Comment: Here you are not passing any data $.ajax({ url : ‘xxx/‘, dataType : 'json', method : 'GET', ..., wher is your data?  you have to pass data:{}

Comment: try console.log(data.sidebar_data.fields['username'])

Comment: Hi, The ajax function url - calls the django url and the corresponding view which is a Json response. The get method packs it in the data and outputs it in the success function. This all works fine and console.log(data) also outputs all the data from the database table. I just can't figure out how to access the username.

Comment: Hi Hasan, thanks for your idea but console.log(data.sidebar_data.fields['username']) outputs. an error in chrome dev tools console. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined. I get this for everything i have tried so far. I always gives me this undefined error.

Comment: @provoke2015 check my answer and give me feedback

Comment: Sorry, did not see that. I am getting the following error. Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o. I got this error before and it thought it was because the data was parsed already but i am not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change views.py like this:

```
from django.core import serializers
def data(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        user = User.objects.filter(id=1)
        data = serializers.serialize('json', user)
        return HttpResponse(data, content_type ="application/json")
    return HttpResponse("not a ajax request")
```

and change template like this:

```
$( ".test{{ user.user.id }}" ).click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url : ‘xxx/‘,
            dataType : 'json',
            method : 'GET',
            success: function(data)
            {   
                console.log(data[0].fields.username);
            },
            failure: function(){  
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks Hasan, i just tried this approach but now i get a different error. 
TypeError at /profile/sidebar/57/
<User: xxx> is not JSON serializable

Comment: I just tried your last idea and got the following error. Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o.

Comment: @provoke2015 check it, i test it in my local machine.

Comment: Sun of a gun. This is it. Thank you so much Hasan. Sometimes i try too many things and loose myself in options. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @provoke2015 your welcome dude! please accecpt my answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try `data[1].fields[1]` instead of `data.sidebar_data.fields[1].username`

Comment: Thanks for the approach but i get the same error. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fields' of undefined. I am not sure what i am missing here.